# Extracting list of types using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to write an application which loads an assembly and list outs which assemblies this again depends on. This part is working fine using Assembly.LoadFrom(asmPath) and GetReferencedAssemblies().

I would also like to extract some public information from the dll.
Mainly I want to find classes which implements certain tags (typically Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiControllerAttribute) and the arguments that these functions have.
When I try to call asm.GetTypes(), I get an ReflectionTypeLoadException because Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core is not loaded.

Is there a way to load Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core using the referenced assembly? I am trying to do this for a lot of dlls, so adding a nuget reference in my "assembly examination program" for all the references is not possible. Or is there a better way to get the information I am looking for?

Comment: You might be lucky to get away with `Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)` i.e. forcing the app to load the assemblies from the directory, though this is fraught with issues.

Comment: Gives the same error

Comment: The premise is still the same, the dlls you are reflecting are depending on assemblies, those assemblies could be located anywhere, though will usually (not always) be in the directory where the original assembly is located), if you can load the assemblies needed, the issue should go away... have you checked Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core is actually loaded after you load it?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core is not in the folder, its compiled into the dll or referenced in a different way

Answer (score 0):

Here's an code snipped that I use to find types that implement some generic interface:

```
public static IEnumerable<ImplementedInterface> FindTypesImplementingGenericInterface(this Assembly assembly, Type genericInterfaceType)
    {
        var types = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                    from iface in type.GetInterfaces()
                    where iface.IsGenericInterface(genericInterfaceType)
                    select new ImplementedInterface { Implementation = type, Interface = iface };
        return types;
    }

    public static bool IsGenericInterface(this Type type, Type genericInterfaceType)
    {
        return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericInterfaceType;
    }
```

Also another snipped, but for finding classes from one assembly that implement interface from another assembly:

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> FindTypesImplementingInterface(Type impl_interface)
    {
        var interfaceAssembly = typeof(Contract.IEventWithTopic).Assembly;
        var implementationAssembly = typeof(Handlers.SmartTube.STAccountEventHandler).Assembly;

        var result = from @interface in interfaceAssembly.GetTypes()
                  from implementation in implementationAssembly.GetTypes()
                  where @interface.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Equals(impl_interface)) &&
                  implementation.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Equals(@interface))
                  select new { Interface = @interface, Implementation = implementation };

        return result;
    }
```

The return type is dynamic because there is no class to store the data.
You can create a separate class for storing those results or use a tuple.

You could try replacing interface with attribute and the method should work fine.

> and the arguments that these functions have

[GetMethods()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=net-5.0) gets all the functions the current type has.
[GetParameters()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters?view=net-5.0) gets all the parameter info that current method ([MethodInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=net-5.0)) has.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned above, the problem is that GetTypes() crashes as some of the references are not resolved